# Determine age of iPhone unit

Tags: iphone, hardware

How can I determine the manufacture date/age of any iPhone device? If there is any way for this, please suggest one.

Comment: By how old you mean when was it first buyed ?

Answer (score 2):

This [website](http://www.appleserialnumberinfo.com/) seems to be able to retrieve some information about Apple devices from the serial number.

There is also [this website](http://www.chipmunk.nl/klantenservice/applemodel.html/).